# Problema de Applets en NetBeans 11.0 Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, netbeans-11

Porque los applets no están configurados de forma automática y a la hora de ejecutarlos en NetBeans 11.0 no se ejecutan como en NetBeans 8.0.2 y sale el error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class pruebaapplet.PruebaApplet
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pruebaapplet.PruebaApplet
```

Codigo:

```
package pruebaapplet;


import java.awt.*; 
import java.applet.*; 
public class AppletHola extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) { 
        g.drawString("Hola", 100, 100); 
    } 
}
```

Que debo hacer para que se ejecute ese applet en NetBeans 11.0

Comment: Evitas usar applets   ya que estan deprecated si quieres una base para dibujar algo grafico usa la clase jpanel, jcomponent o canvas, si buscas algo que corren en navegador web buscan algun framework java como wicket o vaadin

Comment: Me parece que tiene razón @JGarnica , en el sitio puedes encontrar ejemplos para dibujar un gráfico:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Java+dibujar

Answer (score 0):

Información obtenida de **Wikipedia** con respecto a los **applets**:

> A partir de 2013, los principales navegadores web comenzaron a
>   eliminar gradualmente el soporte para los applets de tecnología
>   subyacentes que solían ejecutarse, y los applets se volvieron
>   completamente incapaces de ejecutarse para 2015-2017. *Los applets de
>   Java quedaron en desuso desde Java 9 en 2017 y se eliminaron de Java
>   SE 11 (18.9), lanzado en septiembre de 2018*.

Por tanto, las nuevas versiones de los compiladores de Java ya no soportan la ejecución de applets. Sin embargo, sería posible descargarse una versión antigua del compilador y de ese modo poder realizar prácticas con esta tecnología obsoleta.

Link de descarga  -->
[NetBeans 8.2](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/)